# How to get more accurate feedback about when a program is shutdown?

Tags: monitoring

I am running some software that takes a while to quit. It must write some large database files.

I have observed that, if I run the software from within `xterm`, when pressing "quit", the application's name disappears from the panel, but it takes quite a bit longer before `xterm` returns me to the prompt so I can type any additional commands.

I need to know when the application has successfully and completely quit, so that I do not break the database by quitting Xorg too quickly, but running the program from `xterm` aways is quite impractical.

- Is there an alternative means of receiving accurate feedback about when a program has successfully shutdown that does not involve launching it from within `xterm`?

Comment: Let me know if either of those solutions seem workable, if not I can come up with others.

Comment: The first method you listed works well.

Answer (score 4):

#### Method #1 - using watch

One idea would be to use the `watch` command to run a 2 second looping command, perhaps something like `pgrep ...` or `ps ..`.

```
$ watch "pgrep -l sleep"
```

Where "sleep" is my stand-in process that I want to watch to see if it's finished. The output would look like this:

```
Every 2.0s: pgrep -l sleep             Tue Feb  4 22:07:31 2014

24925 sleep
```

When it's done it would look like this:

```
Every 2.0s: pgrep -l sleep             Tue Feb  4 22:07:31 2014
```

#### Method #2 - using wait

You can also use the same approach that I outlined in this Q&A titled: "[Can I somehow add a “&& prog2” to an already running prog1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100801/can-i-somehow-add-a-prog2-to-an-already-running-prog1/100812)". The technique would work for you here if you invoked your GUI tool like this:

```
$ my_database_tool &
[1] 17440

$ wait 17440 && echo "It's done"

...after it's finished...

[1]+  Done                    my_database_tool
It's done
```

Comment: @Village - If this solved your Q can you please mark it as the accepted A so others know you issue's been resolved. Thanks.