# Wait for move directory to be completed before attempting to delete it

Tags: files, nfs, synchronization

I have a process running on one computer that spawns simulations by writing the simulation data to directory `pre/id`. Worker processes then copy a simulation from `pre` to a local disk, which can be on a different computer. `pre` is in a volume mounted with nfs. This part works well.

When a simulation is done, the results are moved to the directory `result/id`, which is what is causing trouble. The supervising process can decide to keep such a directory or to delete it. Occasionally, when it tries to delete `result/id`, the move operation seems to be incomplete, and removing the directory fails.

Everything runs on a variety of linux flavors. The workers move directories around using `mv` and then `touch result/id/done` to signal to the supervising process that the result can be read (and deleted). The supervising process uses [`boost::filesystem::remove_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) to delete `result/id`.

How can I reliably wait for the move operation to be completed, before attempting to delete it?

---

**Added:**
This code moves the result directory to where the supervising process waits for it:

```
mv $tempDir $finishedCasesDir # copy case to result directory
touch $finishedCasesDir/$caseName/done
```

This is the C++ code that waits for `done` to appear:

```
if(is_regular_file(resultPath/"done"))
{
  // get relevant result data
  ...
  // remove result directory
  remove_all(resultPath);
}
```

And the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error'
what():  boost::filesystem::remove: Directory not empty: "results/711a35ed-818e-4084-ab43-47531fdd8d11"
```

Comment: is it a c++ problem or a scripting problem ? because c++ would fit better on StackOverflow

Comment: It's a problem that occurs somewhere between my script moving a directory and my C++ program trying to delete that directory after it has been moved. I thought about posting at StackOverflow, but I thought it might be a good idea to do it here as I might be able to solve the problem using Linux or Unix features.

Comment: You say the mover process creates `result/id/done` to signal that the move is complete. If done correctly, it should be enough for the supervising process to check for this file's existence. So why isn't this enough?

Comment: @alexis your last question is exactly the one I cannot answer. I'll add the relevant code (script and C++) and error message to my question.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `done` does not exist in the directory prior to being moved?

Comment: Yes. Simulations are created using a template directory, and that doesn't contain a file called `done`. When a simulation is run, a possibly existing `done` file is removed before the simulation starts.

Comment: If I understand your C++ code correctly, you're trying to delete the moved directory (that you called result/id) and not the original one (that you called pre/id). This moved directory is definitely not empty. I dont know boost libs but you probably need to erase the files into the dir before deleting the dir or you need to use another boost function who act like 'rm -Rf'.

Comment: `remove_all` removes recursively. Also the code only fails occasionally - I can delete my result directories 15k times without any problems, and then it suddenly fails. That's why I concluded that there's something still being written into the directory by `mv`.

Comment: If the mover script really only creates `done` after `mv` exits, it is not the source of the problem. Either a *different* process sometimes writes in the same directory (could you have id collisions?), or `remove_all` can fail to find and remove all files before removing the directory. What's left in the directory when you encounter a failure?

Comment: Sounds like several cpus/processes are involved ? And you have a race condition that occurs only occassionally. Your locking system depends on touch being atomic, but it isn't. Suppose the touch was interrupted after creating the output but before closing, supervisor comes in quick and removes file then tries to remove directory but can't because files is not actually removed until touch wakes up and closes fd. Just guessing obviously.

Comment: Yes, several CPUs, even different machines. So I need some atomic replacement for `touch done` that works over nfs, or any other way of signalling to another process on another machine that it can harvest a result.

Comment: unless you code around it, accept error backoff a bit and retry, log the event so you can monitor the situation and develop a better approach when needed.

Comment: I'll just `remove_all` in a loop now until the error disappears - a bit brutal but it should have the desired effect without causing any harm. If I leave data in the directory, that could quickly add up to a few TB. Not good.

Comment: @XTian, "`touch` is not atomic?" I don't buy this scenario. On Unix, holding an open file descriptor does not lock the directory entry-- you can unlink away. The inode and blocks won't be freed until the descriptor is closed, but that doesn't get in the way of unlinking the directory.

Comment: @alexis You are correct within a file system, I have added an edit to my answer to help clarify.

Comment: @Christoph, what's left in the directory when you encounter a failure?

Comment: @XTian, sorry but your answer did not clarify. You just state that you found support for your reservations about NFS. What are these problems you read about?

Comment: @alexis I have not yet looked for .nfs files (because I was not aware of them and didn't look for hidden files), but the directories were left apparently empty (which was very puzzling at first), or with varying leftovers from my simulations.

Answer (score 2):

Have you come across the `flock` command?

It provides you a file lock within the filesystem so can be used in shell scripts.

--- edit

After my initial answer above, further edits were made to original post, to which I added comments and a final suggestion of a race condition across several machines which are using nfs, and devised a scenario. This scenario was challenged by @alexis, to which I thought it deserved a reply.

@alexis you are correct when working within one filesystem, but the situation becomes more complicated when nfs mounted file systems are involved.

It is unclear from OP exactly what mix of machines/servers/clients nfs versions are involved, but I thought it was enough to say, "You need a better syncing mechanism than "touch - rm" and indeed, OP suggests it sort of works but has a 1 in 15k chance of failure. So I suggested either, find a better way to sync or code around it.

After a little investigation on the subject, I have found some references that do show "flaws" in nfs that indicate that removing a file does not work as expected across nfs. More over, there is are differences between nfs v3 and v4, specifically to address this flaw, also nfs4 could working differently, but doesn't or else it would break compatibility with older clients.

This [nfs document](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_d2) summarises the situation it describes the *silly rename* that was introduced to code around the problem, and rfc [5661 NFS 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5661#section-18.25.4) provides further detail.

--edit 2

Extract of one paragraph from above references :

> Because of the design of the NFS protocol, there is no way for a file
> to be deleted from the name space but still remain in use by an
> application. Thus NFS clients have to emulate this using what already
> exists in the protocol. If an open file is unlinked, an NFS client
> renames it to a special name that looks like ".nfsXXXXX". This "hides"
> the file while it remains in use. This is known as a "silly rename."
> Note that NFS servers have nothing to do with this behavior.

Comment: I did but I read that it doesn't work on nfs mounts. Also, how would it guarantee that `mv` is actually complete before returning?

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to put the lock file on that file system ?

Comment: What would I use a lock file for in this case? I don't think it would help solving my problem.

Comment: I think the discussion we had (we probably should have moved this to chat) was very useful, so how can we conclude this? I could add as an answer the code I am now using.

Comment: You could add your code as an answer to your own question. I think others would find this useful. tks for the feed back.

Comment: "removing a file does not work as expected across nfs." That's a promising teaser, but in what way? All you've been saying is "don't trust NFS." What does NFS do in this case that will interfere with a recursive `rm`? What exactly does the reference say that's relevant?

Answer (score 1):

#### Idea #1 - alternative approach?

Rather than `touch` a file what if you waited for the `mv` process to complete instead.

```
$ mv $tempDir $finishedCasesDir & # copy case to result directory
$ wait %1 && touch $finishedCasesDir/$caseName/done
```

This will only touch the file when the `mv` process has terminated.

#### Example

Here's an example using the `sleep` command as a stand in for your `mv` command.

*start time*

```
$ date
Thu Feb 13 21:23:33 EST 2014
```

*start simulated "mv" command*

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 28561
```

*we then "wait" for it to finish*

```
$ wait %1 && echo 'all done!'
[1]+  Done                    sleep 10
all done!
```

*confirming that we were waiting for ~10 secs.*

```
$ date
Thu Feb 13 21:23:48 EST 2014
```

*continue*

```
$ ...boost program can then run...
```

#### Idea #2 - NFS issue?

Based on feedback from [@Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115018/wait-for-move-directory-to-be-completed-before-attempting-to-delete-it/115124?noredirect=1#comment178958_115124), I hadn't realized you were working with these files over NFS. I believe Gilles is 100% correct, I too have encountered similar issues when working with files over NFS where a process may still have access to a NFS mounted directory that you're attempting to delete. When you do this NFS will typically create a `.nfsXXXX` file in the directory, which will foil your Boost applications attempts to delete the file since it's effectively not empty.

**NOTE:** Having a shell whose CWD (Current Working Directory) is a sub-directory within this NFS mount is enough to cause this issue.

You can read more about this issue here in this article, titled: [What is this .nfs file and why can I not remove it?](https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=123962105).

*excerpt from above article*

```
% echo test> foo
% tail -f foo
test
^Z
Suspended
% rm foo
% ls -A
.nfsB23D
% rm .nfsB23D
% ls -A
.nfsC23D
% lsof .nfsC23D
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
tail    1257 robh    0r  VREG  176,6        5 3000753 .nfsC23D
%
```

**Notice:** you can use the tool `lsof` to determine what process is maintaining a file descriptor.

#### References

- [Can I somehow add a “&& prog2” to an already running prog1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100801/can-i-somehow-add-a-prog2-to-an-already-running-prog1/100812#100812)

Comment: I'm currently waiting for `mv` to complete without the trailing `&`. Does `mv &` plus `wait %1` really change the situation as far as the filesystem is concerned?

Comment: @Christoph - based on your description that your boost based C app is not able to delete the directory b/c the `mv` has apparently not finished emptying the directory out prior I would say try it and see.

Comment: Same exception thrown by `remove_all`. That doesn't mean that my previous workaround _really_ works better (that might have been luck).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wouldn't help, in fact it has more of a chance of failing. The original code would work if it wasn't for NFS: logically, `done` is only created after `mv` completes. I suspect that there are `.nfsXXX` files left behind on the server which aren't deleted yet; `done` is created locally so it's seen locally without a round trip to the server.

Comment: @Gilles - thanks I think you're dead on that the issue's NFS, I've added that to my A as well.

Comment: I'll try a different approach when I'm back in office (monday), post my final solution (which might be different to what I have now) and see if I can mark an answer as accepted. All comments have been helpful and gave me some insight - thank you all!

Comment: -1 Backgrounding and waiting is a roundabout way of just waiting in the first place.